# Is it possible to achieve "Delayed Execution" with KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, delayed-execution, ksqldb

1. implement KSQL UDF "NOW()"
2. create stream my_notification_stream as select * from my_event_stream where occurTime + threshold 
   < NOW()
3. listening on my_notification_stream topic

Comment: Can you add some more context about _what_ you're trying to do please? What's the use-case here?

Comment: some use case of delayed queue are: 
1. an order was created but not paid, after 30 minutes system will close it automatically.
2. members received renew notification message 3 days before expired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solution you're proposing would work as you expect, as stream data is processed as soon as it can be.  The result is not recalculated as time advances.

However, you may be able to achieve what you want in other ways.

Take the example of wanting to automatically close orders after 30 minutes if no payment has been received.  This can be achieved by left-joining the orders stream with the payments stream, within a window of 30 minutes, and then filtering out any results with a payment. This would give you a stream of unpaid orders:

```
-- create stream of unpaid orders:
CREATE STREAM UNPAID AS 
   SELECT * FROM ORDERS 
     LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS WITHIN 30 MINUTES ON ORDERS.ORDERID = PAYMENTS.ORDERID
   WHERE PAYMENTS.ORDERID IS NULL;
```

The second example, if I understand it correctly, may be more tricky. You can easily build a table of users, including when their subscription ends. However, that is not sufficient to the '3-day before expiry' you need.   The problem is that the `NOW` udf you talk about is only executed when the data is processed, not as wall clock time changes. What you need is some other way of prompting ksqlDB to re-evaluate your expression.

I don't think this is currently possible with ksqlDB, at least not until it supports non-key joins.